# NSIS Control progress bar on InstFiles

Tags: installation, nsis

Is there any way to control the progress bar that is shown on the InstFiles step of the installation?

I have seen tutorials on how to make a progress bar on a custom dialog page, but not how to control the one on InstFiles.

I extract a lot of files and then run a few steps that take a long time, and the progress bar is sitting at around 90% for all of the steps at the end since there were so many files to extract.  I would like to have better control of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [RealProgress plug-in](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/RealProgress_plug-in) will give you more control over the progress bar, if you need to move progress during a ExecWait you might be able to do that if you move the progress bar in a [second thread](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/BgWorker_plug-in).